# How to connect Nitrogen with Couchdb using Ecouch

Tags: erlang, couchdb, nitrogen

I don't understand how to make a connection with nitrogen and couchdb using ecouch, because I have a error on this connection
 CAUGHT ERROR: error-undef
[{ecouch,db_info,["test_suite_db"]}
 I put ecouch in my erlang library path and I create a symlink to support/include.mk (even I don't know if it has necessary). 
Or if anyone know a database how can connect with nitrogen and who to make this connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry if this question is simplistic but I'm unsure on your experience level. But you did run the `make` command in the ecouch directory right?

Also. Consider [couchbeam](http://benoitc.github.com/couchbeam/) or [erlang_couchdb](http://github.com/ngerakines/erlang_couchdb). Both have far better documentation.

Comment: I do the make command
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/local/lib/erlang/lib/ecouch-read-only/src'
make[1]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/local/lib/erlang/lib/ecouch-read-only/src'

Only I want to connect a database with nitrogen, I don't know how to  do it, I try with postgresql and erl4db but it don't work.
I have couchdb version 11, and this database work fine by itself, but with nitrogen no.

Comment: when I try to create a table I have this error:
1> inets:start().
ok
2> application:start(ecouch).
ok
3> ecouch:db_create("test").
{ok,{obj,[{"error",<<"unauthorized">>},
          {"reason",<<"You are not a server admin.">>}]}}


How can I fix it?

Comment: Ahh. Your CouchDB server is password protected. Haven't played with ECouch a year. But looking at the sources it seems that you need to edit the ebin/ecouch.app file and edit the line that says

    {mod, {ecouch, {"127.0.0.1", "5984", [], []}}},

to someting like

    {mod, {ecouch, {"127.0.0.1", "5984", "username", "password"}}},

Comment: First thanks for your response, but I have this error now:
CAUGHT ERROR: exit-{noproc,
                       {gen_server,call,
                           [ec_listener,{get,"/test_suite_db",[]},30000]}}
[{gen_server,call,3},
 {ecouch,db_info,1},
 {blog_posts,get_posts,0},
 {web_index,body,0},

Comment: Function get_posts looks like: 
get_posts() ->
   
    {ok, Return} = ecouch:view_access("myblog", "nitrogen", "flat"),
    RawRows = json_obj:get_value("rows", Return),
    F = fun(X) ->
            json_obj:get_value("value", X)
    end,
    Rows = lists:map(F, RawRows),
    lists:reverse(Rows).